# How to do a grading system with pre-given list of integers in java?

Tags: java

I would like to convert a list of marks given to grade.

```
public static void main (String[] arg){

   int[] m= Student.getMarks();

}

public static char grade (int[] m){
  int[] lowestg = {80,70};
  char[] g = new char[m.length];
  for (int x=0; x<m.length; x++){
    n=0;        
    for (int y=0; y<m.length; y++){
       if (m[x]>=lowestg[0]){
        g[y] = 'H';
       }
       else if (m[x]>=lowestg[1]){
        g[y] = 'D';
       }
       else 
        g[y] = 'F';
    }
  return g;
  }
 }
```

I would also like to put that into an array of characters.

When I tried to build it, it is shwoing

> error: incompatible types

Comment: I think the problem is in 'HD'

Comment: the last return statement is also unclear. what is 'grade'?

Comment: what type is returned by `getMarks()`? what is the meaning of your why the lowest g array and not just constants for 80 and 70?

Comment: integer

Then I have to convert that to grades and return an array of characters

Comment: to improve the readability of your code i suggest using constants with meaningful names like this `private static final TELL_WAHT_80_MEANS = 80;` and use the constants in your further code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unclear. I guess this is what you want.

```
public static char[] grade(int[] m) {
    char[] g = new char[m.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        if (m[i] >= 80)
            g[i] = 'H';
        else if (m[i] >= 70)
            g[i] = 'D';
        else
            g[i] = 'F';
    }
    return g;
}
```

It's `public static char[] grade(int[] m)` not `public static char grade(int[] m)` in my code.

Comment: Thanks alot I had tried to change it but it is still showing "error: incompatible types" at "return g;"

Comment: @userpane I changed my code since I found you change `'HD'` into `'H'`.

Comment: Thanks alot... I think I forgot that char[]

Answer (score 3):

```
 g[y] = 'HD'  --> HD is not a char...
```

You can change the char [] g, to 
        String [] g